# Django Timezone

Tags: django, timezone

I have a PostgreSql database with localtime UTC:

```
client=# SHOW TIMEZONE;
 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 register)
```

And a table with the release date that shows me 12:15 hours, according to UTC:

```
db=# SELECT datetime_register FROM appointment;
   datetime_register    
------------------------
 2018-08-15 12:15:00+00
(1 registro)
```

In the Django project, I have settings.py defined:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
```

When I check the date on the project, it is presented in the same way as in UTC: 12:15 and should show 09:15, which is the time in Sao Paulo, as defined in settings.py.

What is left to do for the Django project to display the date as TIME_ZONE set in settings.py?

Comment: You use `USE_TZ = True` in settings.py?

Comment: Yes:
```USE_TZ = True``` in settings.py

Comment: How do you "check the date on the project"? As described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates), Django only coverts to the active time zone in templates.

Comment: Ok, solved with 
`{% load tz %}` and `{% localtime on %}`
Thanks